# What is the difference between using Apache-Jena's methods and Apachce-arq(writing sprarql query inside java) to query rdf graph

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web

As far as I know, Apache-Jena Java libraries have some methods such as `ListStatements();` `ListSubjects();` `listSubjectsWithProperty(Property p, RDFNode o);` and so on. Shortly, they can be used to query graph i.e. model (I assume they are for the same usage). On the other hand, by using jena's `com.hp.hpl.jena.query` package, we can also write spraql queries into a java file to query graphs too. So I wonder, which of these could be better ? There are any performance differences between them? And finally, do you know something that can be handled with one of them while the other is not capable of doing it?

Comment: May I ask the reason for -1?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I suspect it was done because whoever voted thought your question is not a very good fit for StackOverflow.  A lot of what you're asking about is either fairly obvious with a bit of research / documentation reading, or is an invitation to extended discussion. StackOverflow is meant for very specific programming questions that can be answered definitively and subjectively, it's not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

The API calls only deal with what in SPARQL terms is a single triple pattern.  SPARQL can provide more complicated patterns and value-based filtering.

Comment: thanks for reply, If possible could you provide a basic example and a query which can be perform by SPARQL but cannot be done by the API? ( It does not have to be a complete example, I just want to understand it clearly and I'm completely new in this area)

Comment: `SELECT * { ?book dc:title ?title .  ?book dc:creator ?creator }`

It's not such much as "can't be done by API", but that the amount of app code needed to make ever more complicated patterns makes having a query language worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you so much to answer my question and provide example, rather than just voting down.